# The type org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, jsp, solr

I am calling a java class from a jsp page and the following exception:

```
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
  An error occurred at line: 18 in the jsp file: /jsp_test.jsp
  The type org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException cannot be resolved.
```

It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

```
 if(request.getParameter("query") != null)
 {
 solrj_api i=new solrj_api();
 i.index_xml();
 }

 %>
```

solrj_api is the java class and index_xml is the method which I want to call.
I have imported following :

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.XMLResponseParser;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.CoreAdminRequest;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.CoreAdminResponse;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.UpdateResponse;
```

when I run the program independently without a call from jsp it works fine.
I have also included all the jars in the build path.

Why do i get this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have all the jar files from \solr-\dist to your servlet container's (Tomcat) lib directory.  The class org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException is in solr-solrj-.jar file and needs to be available at run time. Also make sure to restart your Tomcat.

Comment: yes, it worked, i copied all the jars to tomcat lib folder,but now i get this error: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /jsp_test.jsp at line 21 :   20: solrj_api i= new solrj_api();
21: i.search(query);(this is on line 21)